# Nodejs application hosted on EC2 instance fails to connect to Postgres RDS instance with error password authentication failed for user bitnami

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

When using curl to access a route which performs an axios GET request and queries my database, my Nodejs application fails to connect to an RDS instance even when supplied with the correct connection string, as follows: `const connectionString = 'postgres://bitnami:<password>@<host>:5432/<database>`. The error I am getting is `error: password authentication failed for user "bitnami"` .

For further clarity, my `dbconfig.js` file is as follows:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { Pool } = require('pg');

const connectionString =`postgres://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`;

const pool = new Pool({config: connectionString});

module.exports = { pool };
```

The variables supplied by the `.env` file to `dbconfig.js` are all correct, as I have no issues in accessing the database from within the EC2 instance by running command `psql --host=<host> --port=5432 --username=bitnami --password --dbname=<dbname>` and inputting the password when prompted.

Is the RDS instance not reading the connection string somehow? How can I fix this?

EDIT: Here is the error in full:

```
error: password authentication failed for user "bitnami"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/bitnami/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/bitnami/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/home/bitnami/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.stream.on (/home/bitnami/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Does the password contain characters that need URI encoding?  What does the log file say about the failure reason?

Comment: @jjanes password for user bitnami does not contain any characters that need encoding, it's solely just alphabets and numbers as it is a test account created for testing the database connection. If by logs, you are referring to the RDS logs, I am unfortunately I am unable to view the logs just yet, at least not until devops gets back to me.

Another strange behaviour is that even if I were to change the `DB_USER` in my `.env` file to a different database user, it still throws the same error, `error: password authentication failed for user "bitnami"`.

Comment: Then it sounds like your .env is not actually being used.  Can you have the code log/print the connection string and see what is actually in it?

Comment: @jjanes a `console.log()` of the connection string returns `postgres://bitnami:password@host:5432/database`, so it seems that the variables from `.env` are being passed correctly. Sorry, what do you mean by code log though?

Comment: I just meant to have your code (program) "do a log and/or do a print".  If you change the .env, is that change reflected in what gets logged?  Perhaps they agree only by accident at the moment.

Comment: Yes, whatever changes to the variables in the `.env` file are reflected properly when logging the connection string. I've added the full error in the original post, in case it's necessary.